cin в visual sudio code на C++
Я начал писать код на с++ в visual studio code и все было нормально. Но когда я захотел ввести команду для получения информации от пользователя( std::cin )  у меня пошло что то не так. Команда std::cout сработала но почему то я не могу ввести код у меня просто не пишется и даже не нажимается пробел и ентер. Вот собственно мой код:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int b;
string i;
void sol() {
    std::cout << "Хотите поменять ваш интджер? ";
    std::cin >> i;
    if(i == "да") {
        cout << "На какой?";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "Ваш сегодняшний интеджер это: " << b;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Как хотите";
    }
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int a;
    a = 2 + 2;
    std::cout << "сегодняшний интеджер: " << a;
    sol();
    return 0;
}


Скриншот всего окна VSC сделайте.

Скорее всего это потому, что вы используете Code Runner. Почитайте официальные туториалы, как настроить tasks.json и launch.json.

@HolyBlackCat добавил фото

@HolyBlackCat хорошо щас посмотрю

На предоставленном скрине даже не терминал. Это просто вкладка OUTPUT - выводит разную диагностическую информацию и не служит интерфейсом ввода. Код должен работать именно на  вкладке TERMINAL, точно так же как в обычном системном CMD.

@AlexanderLonberg спасибо проверю

@AlexanderLonberg в терминале у меня просто даже не дают ввести информацию, код просто выводит std::cout а std::cin он будто игнорирует и не дает мне ввести информацию
